# Is there a way to re-write my PWA from Vue to React and not break it for existing users?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vue.js, progressive-web-apps, service-worker

I have a PWA built with Vue which hundreds of users use on a daily basis. There is, of course, a service worker which caches all of the static assets. Whenever a new release is pushed and deployed, a button appears which prompts the user to update their PWA to the latest version.

We're undertaking a complete re-write of this app and would like to use React + Next.js now instead of Vue.

Is there any *sane* way to make this transition smooth for our users? I would like for them to be served the new app whenever we deploy it but looking at how all the underlying files are going to be different, those who have the previous service worker installed will never get served the new, completely re-written app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about pushing an update to the existing version that makes the service worker do some kind of check to see if it needs to clear itself? Like check a hash, file, date, or something similar, to know when to invalidate/clear itself and load the new thing instead.

That way when you upload the new version, the old one will see the new one is up and can reload into the new one.